# javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var a=asdf;
var b=asdfs;
//var a = new String("asdf");
    if (a.equals(b)) {
        $("#package").show();
    }
    else {
          $("#package").hide();
    }

});
```

Comment: What's the error? Why the extraneous `});` at the end? Are `asdf` and `asdfs` really variable names, or did you mean to put them in quotes? The more effort you put into your question, the better both the quality and quantity of your answers. Manoj was kind enough to fix your code formatting -- look at the hints on the right-hand side when you're typing your question (and or reading the editing help: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 6):

You need quotes around your strings, and there is no `.equals()` method in JavaScript, overall:

```
var a="asdf";
var b="asdfs";
if (a === b) {
    $("#package").show();
}
else {
    $("#package").hide();
}​
```

Or, since there's a [`.toggle(bool)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle2) shortcut, more simply:

```
$("#package").toggle(a===b);
```

Comment: you can even use slideToggle() if you want to animate it! :)

Comment: @jimplode - something to keep in mind is `.slideToggle()` *doesn't* have a boolean overload, though you could make one easily enough it's not as straightforward since an animation may be in progress.

Comment: If `a` and `b` are both strings then there's no need to use `===`, so it seems a little generous to award a +1 solely on that basis.

Comment: @Tim - It's unclear from the question if that's always the case, it could be `var a=0, b="0"` as well, better to be safe IMO.

Comment: Nick: yes, no criticism intended.

Comment: @Tim - oh I know :) that was much more for others reading this, sorry I don't make that clear most of the time...above all I consider questions/answer/comments as a google resource, even before they're actually responses  :)